# how can i declare varchar column value in database to be readed by Double array?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a column in a database table with values

```
 16473
 907
 907
 907
 907
 907
 907
 907
```

it is `varchar` type in the database.
How can I convert it to an array type double?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything yet? If so, please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to write a function in your code, which take comma separated string values(i believe you have comm separated values in your column) and will return you double array.

Call Function for Convert String to double.

```
 double[] tmpArray = StringToDoubleArray("12,13,14");

 private static double[] StringToDoubleArray(string strNumbers)
        {
            List<double> dblValues = new List<double>();
            Array.ForEach(strNumbers.Split(",".ToCharArray()), s =>
            {
                double currentDouble;
                if (Double.TryParse(s, out currentDouble))
                    dblValues.Add(currentDouble);
            });
            return dblValues.ToArray();
        }
```

Thanks
Suresh